# How to create some large 3-regular planar graphs

Tags: graph-theory, coloring

I'm looking for a way to produce very large (100-2000 vertices) 3-regular planar graphs.

I've tried to use plantri (plantri -m5 -v 100), but I was not able to produce only random examples (10-50 graphs) and the entire set of graphs with a lot of vertices is too big.

Any other place or way I can produce large graphs?

Comment: It might be worth looking at https://www2.informatik.hu-berlin.de/alkox/forschung/planar/cubic.pdf

Comment: You can apparently ask plantri to give you a 'portion' of the results using arguements. See the "MORE ON RES/MOD SPLITTING" part of the manual here http://users.cecs.anu.edu.au/~bdm/plantri/plantri-guide.txt

Comment: Ok, it's a little more complicated than that, as you have to change the value of "splithint" to be greater than 64.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A program like plantri is very fast considering that it can generate exactly one member of each isomorphism class - which is arguably the trickiest part.

If you only want a small number of random graphs, and you don't care too much about the uniformity of the random selection, then it seems like an approach like:

1. Generate a random triangulation (T) with minimum degree 5 (-m5
   flag,right?). **It looks like the [PlanarMap](http://www.lix.polytechnique.fr/~schaeffe/PagesWeb/PlanarMap/index-en.html) program of Gilles Schaeffer could do this. (see below)**.
2. Form the dual of T to get your graph G.
3. Optionally check for duplicates - which is quite quick for planar
   graphs.

Of course, now we have to do step 1) - but I find it hard to believe that there are no existing approaches for generating random triangulations...

---

Edit: So there is an approach to generating random planar triangulations due to Gilles Schaeffer ([paper here](http://www.lix.polytechnique.fr/~schaeffe/Biblio/Sc99.ps)) that claims to be :

> This simple pseudo-algorithm is linear on average and gives in a few seconds random maps with up to one million edges or vertices

so it looks like it could handle your use case :)